# Neither the plates nor the serving bowl "goes" or "go" on that shelf?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, disjunction

> 1. Neither the plates nor the serving bowl *goes* on that shelf.
> 2. Neither the plates nor the serving bowl *go* on that shelf.

What form of the verb is better in this context, singular or plural? Which is correct and why?

Comment: Answered at  "Neither Michael nor Albert is correct" or "Neither Michael nor Albert are correct"? –  Edwin Ashworth

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you seek the info that's in a decent usage dictionary, such as the *Merriam-Webster's Concise Dictionary of English Usage* (MWCDEU). My copy of *MWCDEU* discusses this very issue on pages 520-1 as #5 of the "neither" entry. :)

Answer (score 2):

Obey your manual of style, either the one you choose or the one thrust upon you.  I use *The Chicago Manual of Style*, which says to choose the number of the noun closest to the verb.

Neither the plates nor the serving **bowl** **goes** on that shelf.
Neither the serving bowl nor the **plates** **go** on that shelf.

Comment: Would that be the same for "The plates and the serving bowl"? If so, it seems wrong to me. If not it seems inconsistent (The Chicago Manual of Style's rule I mean)

Comment: @Avon: It's not inconsistent. For `and`, the number of the subjects is unambiguously plural. That's not the case with neither-nor.

Comment: @TusharRaj You're quite right. Brain isn't working. Nor is not nand.

Comment: @Tushar Raj It **is** inconsistent. The attempt to use the expression logically, that is. It's bound to be, because you're trying to get one utilisation of a verb to do the work of two  (in different declensions) (The plates do not go on that shelf and the bowl does not go on that shelf). No style guide can do better than a fudge with 'Neither A and B, nor C, ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: No no, I surmised that Avon was talking about this case: ''The plates and the bowl go...", wothout neither-nor anywhere. Judging from his answer, I think he was indeed.